# Play audio file when receiving the call

Tags: android, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play an audio clip onto an ongoing call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900564/play-an-audio-clip-onto-an-ongoing-call)

Suppose we have recorded file in our mobile,when we call to any person,as soon as 
he picked up the call he should listen recorded voice file,which we have recorded
I have gone through the below mentioned links still the problem persists 
[How to play audio file when call starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495506/how-to-play-audio-file-when-call-starts)
http://youropensource.com/projects/532-access-the-incoming-outgoing-calls-using-TelephonyManager
I tried but I didn't get he solution now what I have to do?