# How to get outgoing call is answered in Android

Tags: android, phone-call

I need a way to get the the status when a outgoing call is answered. However, in the OFFHOOK state I am also using to call for the outgoing call(ACTION_CALL). How can I add the awnsered state without overriding the outgoing call activity?

```
public class OutgoingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Intent mIntent;
private String phonenumber = null;
public static boolean wasRinging;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mIntent = intent;

    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

}

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private final Context context;

    public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {


        switch (state) {

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: 

            wasRinging = true;
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                Log.e("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%t", "OFFHOOK");
            if (UIUDialer.isOutgoingCall() == true) {

                //Do my work when outgoing call is detected
            } 

            else if (!wasRinging)
            {

                    Log.e("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%t", "WASRINGING");
                //Do my work when outgoing call is awnsered

            }



            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("finish_incoming"));
            wasRinging = true;
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

            wasRinging = true;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: the state `CALL_STATE_RINGING` is **never called** in the `OUTGOING_CALL` , so the variable wasRinging will be always setted to false.

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API available for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the boolean wasRinging?
(you'll have to make it static and remove the initialization, though)

Comment: Thanks Andreas for you help and time. I edited as per your suggestion. I forgot to tell you that My PhoneStateListner is an inner class to my Broadcast receiver Class. After looking at my log cat when an outgoing call is answered it is not going into the OFFHOOK..Does that make sense?

Comment: wasRinging has to be inside your MyPhoneStateListener class

Comment: Can my class be final? public static class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
               private final Context context;
               private static  boolean wasRinging;

Comment: If you don't want to extend/subclass it any further, sure

Comment: cant get this to work...when outgoing call is answered it does not go in any state (IDLE , OFFHOOK and Ringing) Any idea?

Comment: @user1163234 did you find any solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: No i didnt sorry !