# How to detect that End button is pressed on incoming call to disconnect

Tags: android

I am using **PhoneStateListener** for detecting the state of the call ,  but i want to fire an event when the user presses the **End button** to disconnect the call . From **PhoneStateListener** , we can access only three state **Call_State_IDLE** , **Call_State_RINGNG** , **call_State_OFFHOOK**  , and Call_State_IDLE case fires either  when user terminate the call or the caller terminate the call .

And i also want to find out that if  the caller ends the calls in middle  .

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected) what you want? (Don't think it's about calls ended after answering though)

Comment: no @Keyser , i want to know if user disconnect the call rather then answering the call .

Comment: fairy sure this is impossible.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski , but i want to implement this , is there any other way yo do this ?

Comment: @user1403213 No, I believe this is under the dialer's control. There's no phone state for "hung up."

Comment: no @Keyser , it will give same result when the caller ends the call . or the call is disconnected by network . or if user terminates the call .. but i want to distinguish these .

Comment: @user1403213 ah ok, then yes, that's not applicable.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski , is there not any way to implement this . i need this in my application .

Comment: What you're trying to do is basically "extend" an app, which I believe, in this case, is impossible.

Comment: @user1403213 did you got any solution for your ques??

Comment: @user1403213 still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can know the user has ended the call when the phone state goes to IDLE. u can fire the event you want when PHONE_STATE goes to CALL_STATE_IDLE.

Comment: you didn't understand my question properly  . i want to know from which case the call state comes into IDLE .

Comment: You can't do this.  You just can't, it's not in the API, and it's probably  not accessible from the OS either, as the hardware only exposes a slim interface to the phone.