# Android - make phone call, keeping my activity in foreground, i.e. phone-call in a separate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

Is it possible for a 3rd party Android application on an device that is not rooted, to somehow make an outgoing phone-call, without launching the dialer ? What I mean is that my own Activity (displaying some information, image or video) keeps running in foreground, while the phone-call progresses in the background. Clearly, my Activity needs to be aware of call-state changes (i.e. when call is terminated). My own Activity (not the dialer), would have the "Call" / "Hang-up" buttons.

If possible, kindly share some pointers and hints as to how this could be done. If this is possible via the ITelephony (or other such) reflection based API, even if it is undocumented and hack-based method -- I would like to know about it.

So far in my research, I've come to know of only the method where you place the call directly to a number, without having to open up the Dialer first. However during the phone call, the Dialer application's Activity is open. I cannot show any other information on the foreground. Any alternative workaround, s.a. using Dialog overlay etc., might work as worst-case fallback, though I am not sure if there is anyway to show any "active" content (s.a. images that change, or video) in a Dialog.

Finally, can Fragments be a solution ? Can I show the DialerApplication activity in a Fragment ? I don't think so, but wonder if there's any hack possible for it ?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Is it possible for a 3rd party Android application on an device that
    is not rooted, to somehow make an outgoing phone-call, without
    launching the dialer ? What I mean is that my own Activity
    (displaying some information, image or video) keeps running in
    foreground, while the phone-call progresses in the background?

**Ans.**

It is not possible to keep our application foreground during phone call because the phone call is a system app and has highest priority.

**2)** Clearly, my Activity needs to be aware of call-state changes (i.e.
    when call is terminated). My own Activity (not the dialer), would
    have the "Call" / "Hang-up" buttons.

**Ans.**

Yes this is possible to get notify on call-state changes.
Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected)

Comment: Thanks Biraj. Well, I guess then it'd have to be a significant compromise for what I was hoping to do.