# How to (un)blacklist contact/number in Android?

Tags: android

In Android, how can one add and remove a contact or a phone number from/to the black list. Is there API for that? Surprisingly, I haven't found anything about the matter.

Comment: you can create your own custom list for blacklist number and create a broadcast receiver for incoming call events and check for number

Comment: see also http://android.stackexchange.com/a/16286/6035

Comment: @VivekMishra, will the standard built-in Android call manager remain functional if I create such a broadcast receiver to intercept the incoming calls?

Comment: Yes,It will be functional

Comment: @VivekMishra, actually, I need to add a person to the blacklist when a user rejects a call in the built-in call manager depending on some conditions. Can I do that and how?

Comment: just as true caller do if user rejects a call capture that event and get that phone number and then show popup to user if they want to add that number to blacklist or not. In this caase you have to store your list in database also

Comment: @VivekMishra, how can I capture the event of rejecting a call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected check this link

Comment: @VivekMishra, thank you.

Comment: let me post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own custom list for blacklist number and create a broadcast receiver for incoming call events and check for number.
if user rejects a call capture that event and get that phone number and then show popup to user if they want to add that number to blacklist or not. In this case you have to store your list in database also.
For capturing accept or reject events follow this link
[Detecting call reject event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected)