# Android how to find the outgoing call has been attended using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am not able to detect when an outgoing call has been answered.
I have registered BroadcastReceiver for `PHONE_STATE` broadcast, `onReceive()` method gets called only when a number is dialed/ended but when a call was attended, there was no response.
So any possible way to detect attended outgoing call?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685332/1878148

Comment: Please search the stackoverflow before posting the question. If the above link doesn't answer your question adequately, then do mention the specifics. Thanks.